# Dataframe filter out rows (string) which contain specified words

Tags: scala

Here is my question in Scala. I have a dataframe with one column whose data type is string. For example, the column has 4 values

```
"Abc", "dfea", "skjod", "aaa"
```

And a

```
List = ["ab", "kj"]
```

I need to filter out the rows which contain any value in the list. So, for the above data, I will get the second and the fourth rows.

Here is my code:

```scala
val del_blk = (arg: String) => {
  for (word <- list) {
    if (arg.contains(word)) 1
  }
  0
} 
val blkUDF = udf(del_blk)
df
.withColumn("blk", blkUDF(col("col")))
.filter(col("blk") === 0)
.select("col")
.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val del_blk = (arg: String) => {
  for (word <- list) {
    if (arg.contains(word)) 1
  }
  0
}
```

is equivalent to

```
val del_blk = (arg: String) => {
  list.foreach(word => if (arg.contains(word)) 1)
  0
}
```

I suspect you rather intend something like

```
def containsForbiddenWord(word: String): Boolean =
  list.exists(forbidden => word.contains(forbidden))
```

Comment: i am new to scala could u explain in detail. it doesn't work when a add val blkUDF = udf(containsForbiddenWord(_)) after your definition

Comment: `filter(col("col"), udf(containsForbiddenWord)`?

Comment: it doesn't work..
[error] You can make this conversion explicit by writing `containsForbiddenWord _` or `containsForbiddenWord(_)` instead of `containsForbiddenWord`

Comment: Indeed, due to the overloads it needs `containsForbiddenWord _` or `containsForbiddenWord(_)` instead of `containsForbiddenWord`

Comment: I tried containsForbiddenWord _. [error]  cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.sql.Column, org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction)

Comment: @great223 works for me: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/yHasiFkGTyiV8HbTA6AzHg

Answer (score 0):

It's better not to use udfs in spark as they are not optimised and are slow. You can do this using spark SQL as follows:

```
df.withColumn("blk", col("col").isin(list :_*))
  .filter(col("blk") === false)
```

Comment: hi it doesn't work. can't filter the rows which contain value in the list

Comment: Oh sorry I misread your original question, I'll update my answer